# Unable to mount filesystem as read-write in recovery mode

Tags: read-only, recovery-mode

I deleted two unused user accounts. Now I am unable to login even into my own account.
I rebooted in recovery mode in the root shell and tried to restore the back-up of `/etc/passwd`. However, the filesystem is read-only!

I can only access root shell via recovery.

Can you help me?

Comment: @Jobin There is [an existing bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/friendly-recovery/+bug/996454) for this. You may want to add your vote (the green writing near the top-left of the bug page).

Comment: Thanks @PaddyLandau. Thought it was a security measure rather than a bug. Marked it as it affects me too :)

Comment: Well, it used to work until (I think) 11.10.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If I am not wrong, the filesystem is mounted read-only by default in Recovery mode. To mount it as read-write, go the recovery mode and choose `root`. Now type the following command:

```
mount -o rw,remount /
```

Note the spaces, you'll get an error if you ignore the spaces, or add extra ones too. And then you can copy as you tried earlier.

Comment: If your home is on an extra partition, you may also need the command `mount --all`.

Comment: Any tips for "mount: special device remount does not exist"?

Comment: Figured it out. Enabling network sets filesystem to read/write

Answer (score 0):

Recently on my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, I encountered error "System is running in low-graphics mode" and there is no way you can login or proceed beyond this error screen.

For me this happened when I renamed `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d` directory while I was trying to solve one of the graphics related problems.

#### Workaround:

On the error window, press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f3</kbd> to get to the console. Here the filesystem is mounted but in read-only mode so you can't edit to rename the directory back for correction.

To mount the filesystem in read-write mode, use following command

Command: `mount -o rw,remount /`

It would mount the filesystem in read-write mode. Now you can correct the name of the directory using `mv` command. Then, use `exit` command and **Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd>** multiple times till you get to the UI again.

If required, reboot the system using `reboot` command, now you should be able to login as usual.