# First Boot Not Happening [ 7.471657] Adding 4041724k swap on /dev/sda7 Priority :-1 extents: 1 across :4041724k FS

Tags: installation, boot, dual-boot, grub2

I have been trying to get Ubuntu up and running in dual boot, this is the first time I have tried to install linux. Everything was going well with the install, the progress bar had reached the end of installing files and then I got a black screen with a few lines of writing on it that forced my laptop to shut down.

On booting I was taken to grub, where I have the option to boot in Ubuntu and windows (and some other options), when booting Ubuntu I am sent to a black screen with blinking cursor. I can type there, but nothing else happens. Courtesy of some help here, I was sent to this page -- [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

I followed instructions for `black/purple` screen on booting for the first time, changing **"quiet splash"** to **"nomodeset"** and hitting `ctrl-k`. I am now taken to a **black screen** with a lot of stuff going on line by line and then the last line is:

> [7.471657] Adding 4041724k swap on /dev/sda7 Priority :-1
>   extents: 1 across :4041724k FS

Underneath that line I am left with the blinking cursor again and nothing happens.

Extra Details:

- I installed Ubuntu onto a partition
- I used a USB created with Linux/Live for install
- Using Ubuntu 13.10

Not sure if this detail is relevant but I noticed that Python 3 and some other files were uninstalled after being installed when I watched what files were being written during the progress bar on installation. Just struck me as strange.

Any ideas on what I can do to get things working?

**EDIT:** Here is the output of `sudo apt-get update`:

```
sudo: unable to resolve host (none)
Ign cdrom://Ubuntu 13.10 _Saucy Salamandor - Release amd 64 (20131016.1) saucy InRelease
Ign cdrom://Ubuntu 13.10 _Saucy Salamandor - Release amd 64 (20131016.1) saucy Release.jpg
W: Not using locking for read only file /var/lib/opt/lists/lock
E: Couldn't create temporary file work with /var/lib/apt/lists/Ubuntu%2013.10%20%5fSaucy%20Salamander%5f%20-%20Release%20amd64%20(20131016.1)_dists_saucy_Release - mkstemp (30 : Read - only file system)
W: Not using locking for read only lock file ``/var/lib/dpkg/lock``
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem
```

So I then typed in `sudo dpkg --configure -a`, and I got this:

```
$ Sudo: unable to resolve host (none)
$ dpkg: error: unable to access dpkg status area : Read - only file system
```

**EDIT 2**: Having typed `mount -o rw,remount /` I get this output:

```
mount: /dev/sda6 already mounted or / busy
mount: according to mtab /dev/sda6 is already mounted on /
```

At this point I also typed `mount --all` (although not sure if I need to), but nothing happened. I did this having searched for and followed this -- [How do I boot into recovery mode?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150367/how-do-i-boot-into-recovery-mode)

**EDIT 3**: Here is the pic from gparted - http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=n3k85d&s=8#.UwqTGYXSvIU

Yep, so `sudo dpkg --configure -a` did yield some results. There were a lot lines, particularly "setting up lib" lines such as `setting up libfa0 (0.9.3.5)`. I did notice in the middle of the lines somewhere it stated `package in a very bad inconsistent state`, and the final line read:

```
Errors were encountered while processing :
 libfluidsynth : amd64
```

Then when I typed `sudo apt-get update` I got:

```
sudo: unable to resolve host (none)
    Ign cdrom://Ubuntu 13.10 _Saucy Salamandor - Release amd 64 (20131016.1) saucy InRelease
    Ign cdrom://Ubuntu 13.10 _Saucy Salamandor - Release amd 64 (20131016.1) saucy Release.jpg
    W: Not using locking for read only file /var/lib/opt/lists/lock
    E: Couldn't create temporary file work with /var/lib/apt/lists/Ubuntu%2013.10%20%5fSaucy%20Salamander%5f%20-%20Release%20amd64%20(20131016.1)_dists_saucy_Release - mkstemp (30 : Read - only file system)
    W: Not using locking for read only lock file ``/var/lib/dpkg/lock``
```

...which is almost the same as the first time you told me to `sudo apt-get update` except for the last line - now `E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem` is not there.

Comment: Boot into Ubuntu recovery mode and then post the output of `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: Thanks for stepping in :-) I entered recovery mode and then chose "Drop to roost shell prompt" - which I assume is where I type "sudo apt-get update"? If so I have edited my OP with the output.

Comment: You have to mount the ubuntu partition in read wirte mode, see http://askubuntu.com/a/254238/202806

Comment: I tried `mount -o rw,remount` and nothing seemed to happen, so I though that `-o` maybe `-0` and tried `mount -0 rw.remount`, and some stuff happened. I then searched and found http://askubuntu.com/questions/150367/how-do-i-boot-into-recovery-mode -- so realizing that it is actually `-o` and not an `-0`, I rebooted and typed `mount -0 rw,remount /` and this time a few lines printed, which I have put in the OP.

Comment: Oops on the last sentence of my last comment I meant to say `rebooted and typed "mount -o rw,remount /" and this time a few lines printed`,  and not  `rebooted and typed "mount -0 rw,remount /" and this time a few lines printed`.

Comment: Hello, any more ideas Avinash? :-)

Comment: Now try `sudo dpkg --configure -a` or `sudo apt-get update`.And also boot Ubuntu live disk, take a screenshot of gparted partition Editor and finally post it here.

Comment: Thanks. So I booted into Ubuntu from my Live USB with the "Try Ubuntu" option - I believe that is what I was supposed to do? If so I took a pic of gparted. I added that pic to the OP (EDIT 3) along with the other info you asked for.

Comment: yes, click on try Ubuntu option and then open gparted from dash.OP means original poster(you) it doesn't mean your question.So this line "I added that pic to the OP along with the other info you asked for." will look like "I added that pic to my question along with the other info you asked for."

Comment: Hehe - I always thought OP meant "opening post". Ok that is what I did, run Ubuntu through 'try Ubuntu'. I have added that info to my opening post.

Comment: Now try to boot your pc from HDD.What was displayed on the screen?Is there grub shown on startup?

Comment: Yep, grub is always showing on start up since I did the install.

Comment: After selecting Ubuntu from the grub list, your screen displays what?

Comment: I get the same black screen with a flashing cursor, I can type in there but nothing else happens.

Comment: did you able to login into virtual console(ctrl+alt+f1)?

Comment: "virtual console", that's a new term for me. When/Where do I type (ctrl+alt+f1)? When I have the black screen with blinking cursor?

Comment: press ctrl+alt+F1 keys on your keyboard when the black screen appears.

Comment: Ohh You have enough rep we can talk here http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11833/room-for-avinash-raj-and-whoever-wants-to-make-company

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We discussed about the problem in [this](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/13986570#13986570) chat room.I thought that something weired happened during the installation process.So i asked him to reinstall Ubuntu on the same `/dev/sda6`partition.He does it and it works for him.

[image]

### Steps:

- Boot Ubuntu live disk and choose Install Ubuntu option on startup.
- After that choose "something else" option,so that you can be able to install Ubuntu on a partition where we wants.
- Choose `/dev/sda6` and format it to ext4 filesystem.
- Then install Ubuntu on the same formatted partition.
- After the installation completed, remove your installation medium and boot from your HDD.
- Grub will appears and prompts you to choose the Os's on startup.